# How to pause with an MVC structure

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I want to change the color of a panel for a second and then switch back to the original color, I've tried with Thread.sleep but apparently it skips the section where the the first color changes

```
public View(Model model){
    this.model=model;
    initComponents();
    model.addPropertyChangeListener("change", new PropertyChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            panelGreen.setBackground(new Color(153,255,153));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            jButton1.setText("hello");
            panelGreen.setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with ' but apparently it skips the section where there's the first color changes'?

Comment: Sleeping on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) freezes the GUI, see [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). In detail, this means that you will never see the background change since the EDT, which is responsible for updating the GUI, is busy sleeping, after that, the background is reset. As a solution, use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). On `propertyChange` then modify the background color, build and start the timer which will reset your background color and change the text.

Comment: it doesn't change the colour but after a second it changes the text of the button